# Install Root certificate(.crt) file programmatically and make it trust by android device

Tags: android, certificate, openvpn

So, I'm making a VPN Android App based on [OpenVPN](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn). So far everything works fine like connecting/disconnecting `.ovpn` profiles. But now I want to connect with profiles which need certificate authentication. For that I guess we need to install `.crt` file into the android system and that too silently in the background without making user aware about it.

What i found till now:

1. `.crt` file can only be added to android system from Settings manually by user.
2. Even after adding it manually any android app cannot make this `.crt` file trusted (so it shows in notification panel that your network stats can be monitored).

Please help what can be done now ?